How to detect ActionText rich text has changed?
i have model Article and its rich text content as below
# app/models/article.rb
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  has_rich_text :content
end

Now whenever i save an article, how do i know that this article's content has changed
article.update(name: 'test', content: 'test content changed')
article.previous_changes
# {"name" => , "updated_at" =>}
# no content in above list

article.name_previously_changed? # true
article.content_previously_changed? # undefined method


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65948472/observe-rails-actiontext-for-changes

The content is not the Article model attribute so all detect-changed support methods like content_previously_changed? will not defined. But content is an attribute of the Article model's association ActionText::RichText, so here is my simple solution:
article.rich_text_content 
# <ActionText::RichText:0x00007fd81bc66ba0
 id: 2,
 name: "content",
 body: #<ActionText::Content "it updated">,
 ...

article.rich_text_content && article.rich_text_content.body_previously_changed?

